# Sistema de mensajes privados en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de mensajes privados en PHP, de momento he conseguido que se muestren los mensajes privados que tiene un usuario, con el siguiente código:

```
 <div>
    <?php
    require_once "messages.php";

    //obtengo todos los mensajes privados del usuario con id=3 (de prueba)
    $private= Usuarios::GetPrivate(3);

    //obtengo el usuario que escribió cada mensaje
    foreach ($private as $priv) {
       $id= $priv->emisor_id;
       $usuario = Usuarios::GetUser($id);

    //imprimo el usuario
    foreach ($usuario as $usu){
        echo $usu->user;
        echo "<br>";
        ?>

    //incluyo un botón para responder
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo "responder a ".$usu->user ?>" name="button" id="button">

        <?php

    }
    //imprimo el mensaje
    echo $priv->message;
    echo "<br>";
    ?>

    -----------------------------------------------------
    <br><br>


</div>
```

Me gustaría saber si alguien podría darme alguna indicación sobre cómo hacer para que el usuario pueda responder directamente a un mensaje privado. La tabla de mensajes privados tiene los campos id, mensaje, emisor_id y receptor_id. ¿Debería añadir algún campo más?

Comment: Yo que tu crearía "temas/hilo/conversacion"(yo la llamare hilo para el ejemplo) y una tabla N:M para usuario-hilo o como quieras llamarlo en el cual si son privados solo tendrás que agregarlos a los 2 y bloquear la invitación a un tercero. Así que tu tabla quedaría id, mensaje, emisor_id, hilo_id.